# Why is the element I'm trying to delete undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, that when you hit a button, an element is deleted. I've tried a lot, and no results. I've done `document.getElementsByClassName('GDhqjd').remove()` and it's not defined. I've also done `var nam = document.getElementsByClassName('GDhqjd')` and then `remove(nam)` but remove becomes "undefined" I can't find a solution anywhere. How would I get the js to delete the elements?
Full Code

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('GDhqjd').remove()
}
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: You are getting a list of elements with getElementsByClassName - try doing `document.getElementsByClassName('GDhqjd')[0].remove()`

Comment: Please give the exact error message.

Comment: I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).remove is not a function` for the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that error message. Also, edit your original text since the error message has nothing to do with "undefined".

Comment: TLDR, you get a `TypeError` because the `getElementsBy*()` methods return an array and an array does not have a `remove()` method.